# How do I convert my Xcode C++ terminal app to build on a plain ole Linux box?

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, macos

I have a 3D rendering app written in C++ and built on Mac OS with Xcode. I link to OpenEXR libraries. This is a simple "headless" terminal app. No UI.

I want to rebuild this app on a Linux box deployment on a AWS or some other cloud platform.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is the libraries you use available for your Linux system of choice? Can it be built? Then there's really not much more you have to do than to rebuild your application.

Comment: Yah, OpenEXR is the image library. I'm sure it is available for Linux. I's be a while since I built on Linux. Back to makefiles? Any pointers?

Comment: Yes makefiles is one way to go. Or find another IDE.